# Alert when a virtual machine has been resized

Tags: azure, resize, virtual-machine, alert

Within Azure Portal, is it possible to have an alert fire when a virtual machine has been resized manually?  Autoscaling is not enabled so I am looking to have an alert triggered by the resizing of a virtual machine manually.

Is it as simple as configuring the 'Create or Update Virtual Machine (Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines)' alert?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is that simple. But it will also give you alerts that are not caused by resizing.

There is an explaination here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-activity-log